# Error by RPSystemBroadcastPickerView "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions"

Tags: swift, replaykit, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

I am using RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to enable the user start broadcast in simpler way.
I've created new iOS "Single View App" project, added the code to ViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let screenSharingProviderPickerView: RPSystemBroadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: view.frame)

        view.addSubview(screenSharingProviderPickerView)//append(screenSharingProviderPickerView)//insertSubview(screenSharingProviderPickerView, at: 0)
        screenSharingProviderPickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([screenSharingProviderPickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
                                     screenSharingProviderPickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
                                     screenSharingProviderPickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                                     screenSharingProviderPickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)])
}
```

Build and run project on a device, tap to white-black circle in the middle of the screen, BroadcastPickerView appears, but at the same time I've got error message to the console:
**Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x109301750.**

Are there any workarounds for this "Unbalanced call" error?